# Is it ok with self-signed ssl certificate for mobile apps?

Tags: ssl

I was thinking, since I controll the app and what site it points too (and since I of course control the server as well), is it a security issue if the SSL certificate is self signed? The entire point of having a verified certificate is so people know that you are who you say you are right? When I controll who people are talking too anyway, what use is it to have a verified certificate?

Comment: How will you differentiate yourself from the person impersonating your server using a MITM attack?

Comment: Since I controll the client, I controll the authorization as well. The mobile client could always check the certificate against a pre-defined hash, right?